# Search Keyword based instead of Document search

Tags: javascript, php, search, web

I am doing a project on personalized web search.
I created a offline site which searches documents from my site and i use PHP and JavaScript to build that.
i want to perform simple search based on the keywords instead of document search ,what i need to change in the following java script to perform basic search based on keywords from my site.

The code snippet  for the following search using java script is as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
/* initialize the data "filetype" */  
$("#types a:first").click();  
$("#types a").click(   
function () {              
$("#types a").each(  
function(){  
$(this).css({ "background-color":"",  "padding" : "",     "color":                    "#6599CB",fontWeight:"normal"});  
}  
);  
$(this).css({ "background-color":"#6599CB", "padding" : "5px", "color":"white", fontWeight:"bolder"});  
return false;  
});


    function updateLink() { 
    $("#google").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI($("#word").val()) + "+filetype%3A" + encodeURI($("#types").data("filetype")));  

    }
```

`enter code here`

```
$("#types a").click( function () { 
        $("#types a").each(  
            function(){  
                $(this).css({ "background-color":"",  "padding" : "", "color":"#6599CB",  `enter code here`fontWeight:"normal"});  
            }  
        );  
        $(this).css({ "background-color":"#6599CB", "padding" : "5px", "color":"white", fontWeight:"bolder"});  

        $("#types").data("filetype", $(this).attr("value"));                      
        updateLink();        
        $("#word").focus();  
        return false;  
    });

/* update the link when "#word" changes */  
$("#word").keydown(function(e){  
updateLink();  
}).keyup(function(e){  
/* submit search with "enter" key */  
if(e.keyCode == '13') enter code here{  
$("#google").click();  
}  
}); 
});
```

It is a java script code where the search is based on document types like Doc,pdf etc 
but instead of that if i want to perform simple search based on the keywords ,what is the change i need to make in this java script ,please help me friends to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
$("#google").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI($("#word").val()) + "+filetype%3A" + encodeURI($("#types").data("filetype")));
```

to this:

```
$("#google").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI($("#word").val()));
```

that way you'd cancel search by filetype and get only keyword search results.

Comment: Thanks Volkan Ulukut for your answer ,i have one more query on this search ,whenever i try to search the last letter is always missing while clicking the search button (i:e)for example ,if i try to search the keyword "jquery" ,the search function ignores the last letter and it searches like "jquer" ,how to fix this ,please help me and i asked you for simple search ,if we want to search for specific images type or videos what code i need to add or replace to the old code ,thanks in advance ,please reply me

Comment: because you are updating the link on "keydown". this event fires before the key is pressed so your last character can't be added to url. just put it on "keyup" instead. for your other questions, do a manual search in google and copy the link from address bar. then try to convert your url to output the same format as google does.

Comment: thanks for your help again Volkan Ulukut regarding the keydown ,it works perfectly without missing any letters but regarding the search for images and videos,  i tried to grab the format from google for search images and videos ,but it doesn't work properly, i am really sorry ,but if you can help me out in that code,it will be great,thanks in advance.

Comment: just add "&tbm=isch" for image search and "&tbm=vid" for video search. to thank me you could upvote my answer as well :)

Comment: thanks for the info, i will definitely up vote ,  you told me to add the above for images and videos but i get 400. That’s an error. message ,can you please post that specific code ,sorry for that ,help me please ...